# PHP destroy session when leaving a page out of session

Tags: php, session, destroy

I currently have an admin page but the session is only destroyed when the admin logs out. What I would like to do is destroy the session if the admin leaves a page that has sessions (e.g. admin.php) and goes onto a page without sessions (e.g index.php or a different website) how can this be done?

Comment: You'll never know if the user goes onto a different website unless that website calls some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the [session_timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes) to your desired value and be sure not to add 'session_start()' to your non-session pages, or explicitly log them out on those.

Comment: how would i use session time_timeout for killing the session after 10mins

Comment: Did you follow the link?